# mix.version() doesn't build what I expected

Tags: laravel-elixir

Here is my mix:

```
mix.styles(paths.styles, './', 'public/css/app.css')
    .scripts(paths.vendors,'./','public/js/vendor.js')
    .scriptsIn(paths.app,'./public/js/app.js')
    .version(['css/app.css','js/vendor.js','js/app.js']);
```

My expected result in build directory would be these below files with revision:

- app.css
- vendor.js
- app.js

But after I ran `gulp`, I got only `app.css` and `app.js`.

Is there something wrong with my mix?

Comment: As far as I can tell it's not an issue with your mix, the issue is that you can only have one file from each folder versioned. I'm not sure why but if you compile your vendor to vendor/vendor.js instead of js/vendor.js it works fine.